# Azure Data Factory Pipeline stuck in "PendingUpdate" provisioning status on deployment

Tags: azure-data-factory, cortana-intelligence

I am a having a problem for the last couple of hours, upon deployment of a pipeline, it goes into the provisioning state and then gets stuck there.

It then eventually fails with one of these two errors:"Failed to reach service" or "Internal Server Error."
The state of the pipeline is stuck at "Pending Update"

I have even created a Data Factory from scratch, created new linked services and data sets, and created the pipeline within that data factory, and the same thing is happening.

What can be causing this issue?

I have to add that I was using DF and deploying pipelines and everything was going well, this was a sudden issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have had occasional service incidents in the past which have transiently impacted provisioning of ADF entities.  If you are still experiencing this issue please open a support ticket with the specific info for your data factory.  We appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Yes, it resumed normal functionality after some time. Thanks.

Comment: Tayyab/Sonia, I'm also facing the same issue and this is stuck in "Pending State" since 3-4 days. And also cannot delete the Pipeline from portal or powershell, etc. Please help me.